# 2 arrays are becoming equal

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to do 2 arrays (`arr1` and `arr2`) which size must be from value 3-10 only. To do that I set the range of both of my arrays to var size( as seen in the code). However, after I've inputted the values for `arr1` and `arr2` and then print them, the value of `arr1` became the same as `arr2`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{ 
    int size, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0; 
    int arr1[size], arr2[size]; 
    
    while(a = 1)
    { 
        cout << "Enter desired size of the array: "; 
        cin >> size; 

        if(size >= 3 && size <= 10)
        {  
            break; 
        } 
        a= 1;   
    }
    
    cout<<"\nEnter value for Array 1: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr1[i]; 
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr1[i]; 
    }
    
    cout<<"\nEnter value for Array 2: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr2[i]; 
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout <<"Array 1: " << arr1[i] << " Array 2: " << arr2[i] << endl; 
    }
}
```

output:

```
Enter desired size of the array: 3

Enter value for Array 1:
1
2
3
123
Enter value for Array 2:
5
4
3
Array 1: 5 Array 2: 5
Array 1: 4 Array 2: 4
Array 1: 3 Array 2: 3
```

When I change or set the range of my `arr2` (example `arr2[3]`) the problem disappear. However, I need both `arr1` and `arr2` to have the same size and the size must come from the user. What could be the solution?

Comment: Think about it, in `int arr1[size]`, what value does `size` have? In short, the problem is that C++ arrays are const-sized and your code doesn't account for that. Use `std::vector<int>` instead. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `int arr1[size]` is a non-standard variable-length array, *and* it uses `size` before it is initialized. Just use `std::vector<int>` rather than juggling C arrays around.

Comment: When using size as an input to your program remember to use dynamic array: `int* tab = new int[size]`. As stated before, you cannot memory of unknown size

Comment: We are tasked to only use array

Comment: Therefore follow my suggestion above

Answer (score 1):

This is terrible code:

```
int size; 
int arr1[size], arr2[3];
```

At the moment of the definition of the arrays, size is not initialized. Furthermore, even if it was, the arrays would be Variable Length Arrays which is indeed a C thing, but is not standard C++ because of various problems in exception handling. They are only accepted as extension to the standard by some compilers, mainly gcc and Clang.

Depending on your compilation options, `size` could be 0 at the time of definition. In that case, the compiler would have make `arr1` and `arr2` be 0 size arrays at the same memory location. Using any of them will of course invoke Undefined Behaviour.

The normal way to create arrays with a size only known at run time is to use dynamic arrays allocated with `new[]` (and later deallocated with `delete[]`)